# JDK11 - How to ignore namespaces during unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, java-11

I'm trying to write a Java 11 XML unmarshaller that strips the namespace data before casting it to an object but I'm getting the following error. The app needs to strip the preceding`app:` from all the elements before being caste to the Object.

How would one do this using JDK11?

**Error**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 67; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"app:exampleXML"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.com/schemas/app}object>]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:453)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:387)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
    XmlUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XmlUnmarshaller.java:36)
    ...
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 67; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"app:exampleXML"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.com/schemas/app}object>
    ...
    ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"app:exampleXML"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.com/schemas/app}object>
    ... 31 more
```

**Test**

```
public void testUnmarshal() throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {

        String xml3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
                "<app:exampleXML xmlns:app=\"http://www.example.com/schemas/app\">\n" +
                "<app:id>app-id</app:id>\n" +
                "<app:time>2020-06-05T13:17:00.899Z</app:time>\n" +
                "<app:type>test</app:type>\n" +
                "<app:description>Test</app:description>\n" +
                "</app:exampleXML>";

        XmlUnmarshaller unmarshaller = new XmlUnmarshaller();
        Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml3, Object.class);

        System.out.println(object);
}
```

**Unmarshaller**

```
public <T> T unmarshal(String xml, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        return clazz.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr));
}
```

**Object**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "exampleXML", namespace="http://www.example.com/schemas/app")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XML {
    public static final int DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 4000;

    @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
    private String id;


    @XmlElement(name = "time", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(InstantXmlAdapter.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = InstantJsonSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = InstantJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Instant time;

    @XmlElement(name = "type", required = true)
    private CheckpointLevel type;

    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CDATAXmlAdapter.class)
    private String description;
```

Comment: Bind the app namespace to the same as the default.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what do you mean by that? I've assigned the namespace in the `XMLRootElement` on the object (see update)

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. It is easy to write Java code that works with namespaces.

Comment: @kimbert because the unmarshalling is only working for XML without the `app:` namespace. Is there a better way to caste this xml data to my Object while maintaining the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Added **package-info.java** to the domain object and added a prefix

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.example.com/schemas/app",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(prefix = "app", namespaceURI = "http://www.example.com/schemas/app")
        }
)
package com.app.domainObjects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```